# Creating a reminder on a date in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created a c# application which needs to show, after the form load, on a datagridview, which will be filled the entries which have the expiration date almost passed (1 month before expiration date). The thing is that I have a local database and I have to compare the current time with the expiration date.Thanks a lot!
There's the query:

```
SELECT  *  FROM [Table] WHERE datediff(month,expirationdate,CURRENT_DATE())<1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You seem to have forgotten most of your question. Especially the part where it provides details about what you are trying to do. This is important so others can help.

Comment: When you write a question, try to imagine the question is on behalf of someone else... if you read this question, would *you* have any idea what was required?

Comment: SO is not for general instruction.  It's for answering specific questions about code you've written and is giving you trouble.  You need a clear, explicit example of the work you've tried and what errors you are getting.  A quick search of the `DateTime` object in .Net via Google is all you really need to answer this question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will modify right now.

Comment: Now you have sort of provided some details but you have no question. What you need here is a question. That means technical details AND an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to compare a variable from a table with the current date. I've provided the code above of what I've tried. It gives me the error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'".

Comment: Ahh see....now we are getting somewhere. You have provided the problem which is now obvious because of the details. CURRENT_DATE is not a built in function in sql server. Try either getdate() or current_timestamp.

Comment: So suppose you have an expirationdate of 17 March 2018 do you want that date included in the resultset? The diff between 2 and 3 is one but the difference in days could be more than 28/30/31 days.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 basic rules about handling DateTimes:

1. Always store, transmit and retreive (STR) the UTC value. If you have a client application, it can translate that into the current Computers timezone (retreived from Windows). You really do not want to [mess with Timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). And only with WebServers will you ever have too.
2. Avoid STR in string format.
3. If you can not avoid STR in string, at least pick a fixed Culture Format and String encoding at all endpoints. You do not want to eitehr of those added to your problems.

If you follow those rules, the actuall processing becomes easy:

```
DateTime dueTime //set someplace else

if(DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1) >= dueTime)
  //Due time is in one month or less
```

Comment: All right, but the variable is in a table. How I can take it as a variable in code?

Comment: You translate if from whatever type your DB uses to whatever type your Programmign languge uses. At least that much google-fu we are expecting of you. Granted in such cases it might be better to solve this whole thing in the DB query itself. But as you seem to be new, pick wichever side the check is easier in.

Comment: While I mostly agree here I don't see how this is answering their question. Your code is a dotnet example where the OP is doing this in t-sql.

Comment: @SeanLange: The tags are C# and SQL Server. Indeed I would never have seen this if it was not for the C# tag.

Comment: What is "STR" ?

Comment: If I care about time zones I use `DateTimeOffset`, ideally in UTC. This removes all ambiguity and has the precision of `DateTime2`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime

Comment: My main difference here is that I have a single rule for datetimes. NEVER store date(time) values as strings. It avoids all those issues. Use a date/datetime datatype in t-sql and a date in your programming language. This avoids ever needing to convert back and forth.

Comment: The thing is that I'm new to C# and I want to learn. I don't know to take the variable from the table. If you can provide me some links, I'll be grateful.

Comment: @Jodrell STR: store, transmit and retrieve; defined in line 1

Comment: I agree that in 95% of the cases, this should be solved in the DB query. I am a bit of fanatic regarding "do filtering in the query". Even if we had much shorter reminder times (like minutes), the case for solving that in the GUI only goes up to 50% at best. But in this case of a beginner, That might just be the 5%. And he needs to figure out how to turn a SQL Datetime into a .NET datetime anyway, if he wants to display this.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT_DATE is a function present in the MySql and Oracle database systems. In SqlServer you use the [GetDate() function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) 
But changing that function is not enough because there are other problems in your query and I think you should change it to:

```
SELECT  * FROM [Table] WHERE expirationdate >= GetDate() 
                       AND datediff(month, GetDate(), expirationdate) between 0 and 1
```

Notice that the second parameter to datediff is the *startdate* and the third is the *enddate*. If your logic is to find all records whose *expiration* date is less than one month from today then the *expirationdate* values is for the *enddate* parameter and the current date is for the starting date. I presume also that you don't want days already in the past, thus I have added also a check to exclude every *expirationdate* lower than today.

This solution is wrong because it still include dates where the month part differs for 1 integer. But an expiration date of 18 March 2018 will be included here when the current date is 13 February 2018 because the differece between 3 and 2 is still 1.

If you want to be more precise then you should search the difference in days not in months.

```
SELECT  * FROM [Table] WHERE expirationdate >= GetDate() 
                       AND datediff(day, GetDate(), expirationdate) <= 30
```

Here I use a normalized value for a month's days of 30.

Comment: It gives me the error that it don't recognize the database anymore, I think there's the real problem.

Comment: Now I am confused by your comment. What error and where? Not in this line I suppose.